# Monitoring websocket logs in Azure Gateway

Tags: websocket, azure-application-gateway

I am aware that Azure application gateway supports websockets. However, I cant figure out from the samples and documentation how websocket access is reflected in the Access Logs.

I have been going over Azure gateway documentation for Access logs over here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-diagnostics#for-application-gateway-and-waf-v2-sku

There is no `protocol` field - which usually carry `ws` or `wss` to indicate websocket access.

Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is no user-configurable setting to selectively enable or disable WebSocket support in Application gateway. WebSocket protocols are designed to work over traditional HTTP ports of 80 and 443. You can continue using a standard HTTP listener on port 80 or 443 to receive WebSocket traffic. WebSocket traffic is then directed to the WebSocket enabled backend server using the appropriate backend pool as specified in application gateway rules.

Here is a clear [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-websocket#how-does-websocket-work) explaining about Websocket workflow in Application Gateway.